# do add_action on condition

Tags: plugins, actions, conditional-tags

This snippet for example will email on EVERY post:

```
function email_friends( $post_ID )  
{
   $friends = 'bob@example.org, susie@example.org';
   wp_mail( $friends, "sally's blog updated", 'I just put something on my blog: http://blog.example.com' );

   return $post_ID;
}
add_action('publish_post', 'email_friends');
```

... whereas I just need add_action to run ONLY if the post is in category say "uncategorized", not any other category.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`has_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_category) to check if a post belongs to a certain category.

```
function email_friends( $post_ID )  
{
    if ( has_category( 'uncategorized', $post_ID )
    {
        $friends = 'bob@example.org, susie@example.org';
        wp_mail( 
            $friends, 
            "sally's blog updated", 
            'I just put something on my blog: ' . get_permalink( $post_ID )
        );
    }
}
add_action('publish_post', 'email_friends');
```

And you don't need to return anything for an action handler.